# XSLT How to split string into multiple elements?

Tags: xml, xslt, split

Im facing a problem which Im struggling with right now for approx 2 days trying to find a solution. I found solutions to every possible choice but not for mine.

I have an XML file on Input consisting of this:

```
<Data>
    <AFU abc="r20r50" def="r14r105" />
    <AFU abc="r201r7" def="r4r165" />
    <AFU abc="r147r502" def="r44r10" />
</Data>
```

for the transform I am using XSLT 1.0 I cannot use the new one thats why Im struggling.

the problem is I need to store values from attributes but I need to split them first. Basically what I need is to separate numbers from letters... I mean something like this:

How output XML should look like:

```
<Data>
    <element>20</element>
    <element>50</element>
    <element>201</element>
    <element>7</element>
    <element>147</element>
    <element>502</element>
    <element>14</element>
    <element>105</element>
    <element>4</element>
    <element>165</element>
    <element>44</element>
    <element>10</element>
</Data>
```

You know what I mean? Basically I need to get rid of those R's and store numbers in each element. I find it pretty hard with XSLT 1.0

can someone help?

Comment: 1. Will there always be exactly two values in each attribute? 2. Does the order matter?

Comment: yes they will... its always going to contain "rXXrYY" it ca r0r200 1 digit and 3 digit num ordering doesnt matter because I need those values (numbers) later on so I can use it as a position in xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="AFU/@*">
            <element>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'r'), 'r')" />
            </element>
            <element>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(., 'r'), 'r')" />
            </element>        
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```